# Max value in list with decimals.

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, max

So, I'm having a lot of trouble finding the largest decimal integer in a massive list of strings (1500ish). Here's what I have within a function (to find the max value):

```
all_data_lines = data.split('\n');
maxvalue = float(0.0);
for item in all_data_lines:
    temp = item.split(',')[1];
    if (float(temp) > maxvalue):
        maxvalue = float(temp);
return maxvalue
```

The data file is essentially a huge list seperated by new lines and then seperated by comma's. So, I need to compare the second comma seperated element on every line. 
This is what I have above. For some reason, I'm having this error:

```
in max_temperature
    temp = item.split(',')[1];
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: There's a line in your data that has no comma.

Comment: Richie, you were exactly right. 
I have probably spent 2hrs on this and you're right. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently have lines that have no comma on them; perhaps you have empty lines. If you are using `data.split('\n')` then you are liable to end up with a last, empty value for example:

```
>>> '1\n2\n'.split('\n')
['1', '2', '']
>>> '1\n2\n'.splitlines()
['1', '2']
```

Using [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) on the other hand produces a list without a last empty value.

Rather than split on each line manually, and loop manually, use the `csv` module and a generator expression:

```
import csv

def foo(data):
    reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    return max(r[1] for r in reader if len(r) > 1)
```

This delegates splitting to the `csv.reader()` object, leaving you free to focus on testing for rows with enough elements to have a second column.

The `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` option tells the reader to convert values to floats for you so you don't even have to do that anymore either. This, however, works only if all columns *without quotes* are numeric. If this is not the case and you get `ValueErrors` instead, you can still do the conversion manually:

```
def foo(data):
    reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines())
    return max(float(r[1]) for r in reader if len(r) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, It was the last line that had no comma. However, I managed to fix it quite quickly using del a[-1]. 
All is sorted, but I shall definitely look into the used of csv.

Comment: @Hbrewitt: then using `str.splitlines()` should be the first thing you switch to; it'll not include a last empty line while `str.split('\n')` definitely will.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't even aware of that. I added that in and all is working perfectly. Thanks for all your help!